# swift language version not supported

Tags: swift, xcode

The project built in `Xcode 10.1`, now i am trying to run it on `Xcode 10.2.1` and i am getting following error.

> The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set
>   to a supported value for targets which use Swift. Supported values
>   are: 4.0, 4.2, 5.0. This setting can be set in the build settings
>   editor.

I tried changing language values in `SWIFT LANGUAGE COMPILER` under build setting to 4.0 and also change the swift version in `podfile`.

i am still getting same error.

Comment: Please check whether you have changed swift version to all the targets in the project.

Comment: yes, but did not work for me.